# Структура программы на с++

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста расскажите про структуру программы на с++. Допустим у нас есть обычная программа на с++:

```
#include <iostream> // директива препроцессора
int a = 12; // declaration statement (объявление)
int main() // описание функции
{
    std::cout << a; 
}
```

Таким образом получается, что вообщем программа состоит из: директив, описаний функций, классов, структур и объявлений (declaration statements). Можете пожалуйста дополнить или что-то исправить, если нужно.

Comment: `int main(){}` - вполне себе программа на С++...

Comment: @Harry, а можно именно про программу, указанную выше.

Comment: Не знаю, стыдно сказать, но меня такие философские вопросы не сильно привлекают...

Comment: Ну вы и сами описали программу

Comment: Ещё есть forward declaration, macros, templates, лямбды. А для MSVC компилятора нет структур, только классы с public по дефолту.